# How to get specific api response path that is in an array with google script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have an api response that looks like this:

```
{
  "dates": [
    {
      "date": 
      "display_date":
      "title": 
      "menu_title": 
      "items": [
        {
          "title": 
       }]
   }]
}
```

I want to get the **title** field. I'm not sure how to do this with Google Script? Tried the below but seems like it doesn't work (getting null).

```
var fetchMenuData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var menuData = JSON.parse(fetchMenuData.getContentText());
var items = menuData.dates.map(({items})=>items);
var itemName = items.map(({title})=>title);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `menuData` is the structure shown at the top, to get an array of `title` under `items` under `dates`, use the following.

```
var titles = menuData.dates.map(date => {
  return date.items.map(item => {
    return item.title;
  })
})
```

Comment: doesn't seems to work for me. still getting null. question. why do we need to go in date again? when we already entered it from menuData.dates.map ?

Comment: The structure shown at the top is made up of `dates`, which is an array, so needs to be `map`ped through. Each of the `dates` elements has an `items` element, which is also an array, each element of which contains `title`. This is why I have used map twice.

I have tested locally. If `menuData` contains what is shown at the top, the code I have written works. Have you done a `console.log(menuData)` after the `var menuData = JSON.parse(fetchMenuData.getContentText())` line to ensure this is what is stored in `menuData`?